# How to make gnatmake tool compile RTS with project?

Tags: ada, gnat

Is there a way to make gnatmake tool recompile the Ada's runtime library ("RTS") with the project I'm building file by file? I want to integrate my custom preprocessor that adds some features to ada source code and then compiles it with gcc. I'm passing `--GCC=<preprocessor>` flag to the gnatmake utility, it figures out dependencies automatically and runs my preprocessor for all of my source files. However I want custom preprocessing to be done on code in the RTS as well, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-a` flag tells gnatmake to recompile any RTS files that need to be recompiled.

After a little experiment here it seems that if you copy `system.ads` (and maybe `gnat.ads`, `interfac.ads` .. yes) from the compiler’s `adainclude/` directory to your source tree (I think you’ll need to `touch` it whenever you update your preprocessor), gnatmake may be able do what you want.

```
$ cp /opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.9.0/adainclude/system.ads .
$ gnatmake -a int
gcc -c int.adb
gcc -gnatpg -c -I./ -I- /opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.9.0/adainclude/s-stalib.adb
gcc -gnatpg -c -I./ -I- /opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.9.0/adainclude/a-except.adb
gcc -gnatpg -c -I./ -I- /opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.9.0/adainclude/s-valint.adb
gcc -gnatpg -c system.ads
...
gcc -gnatpg -c -I./ -I- /opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.9.0/adainclude/s-conca4.adb
gnatbind -x int.ali
gnatlink int.ali
```

and, after I realised I hadn’t used `-gnata`,

```
$ touch int.adb
$ gnatmake -a -gnata int
gcc -c -gnata int.adb
gcc -gnatpg -c -I./ -gnata -I- /opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.9.0/adainclude/s-assert.adb
gnatbind -x int.ali
gnatlink int.ali
```

(I do *not* want to use `-f` here, because it’ll rebuild everything.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Simon! It seems to be doing what I want when I pass `-f` and `-a` flags to gnatmake. By the way I didn't reallize that GNAT compiler is so fast, it recompiles the RTS in around 5 seconds for a hello world project.